# How can I index application JSON log on kubernetes with fluentd and elasticsearc

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I am struggling with my EFK configuration / setup on Kubernetes.
Basically, the stack is working but I am not able to search for application specific logs fields as it's apperently not properly indexed.

My application produces JSON log which is something like:

```
{"level":"info","message":"My log entry"}
```

In Kibana I get this log string for the 'log' field, but I can search for or filter on message for example:

```
kubernetes.namespace_name: development
kubernetes.pod_id: 1bed9caa-685c-400e-ad06-b03ab5155c15
kubernetes.pod_name: my-app-6ffd8fd688-8f5cf
log: {"level":"info","message":"Processing request /"}
```

EFK Versions:

1. ElasticSearch: elasticsearch:7.9.2
2. Fluentd: fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.11.4-debian-elasticsearch7-1.0
3. Kibana: kibana:7.9.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using [kubernetes_metadata_filter](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter)?

Comment: no, I am currently using the default docker images only, no additional config yet